# What vendors set up permanent shop?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

> One thing Isabelle recommends as a means to improve your Animal Crossing: New Horizons island rating is to **encourage new businesses to flock to your island**. However, that's not exactly an easy task. But, what you can do is **make sure you interact with** any of the travelling salesfolk that rock up on your island. Think Sahara and her rugs, Kicks and his shoes, Flick and CJ with their bug and fish fetishes respectively, and you get the idea. Make friends with them, interact with them, buy from them, and it'll go a long way to improving what people think of your island. **Even if they aren't ready to set up a permanent shack on your shores just yet.** 
>   https://www.gamesradar.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-island-rating-how-to-improve/

I know that one vendor moves to a permanent location...

> the Mabel sisters

...but are there any others? Do Sahara, Kicks, Flick, CJ, or any other businesses set up permanent shop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only **Able sisters** set up a permanent shop.

https://web.archive.org/web/20200323185853/https://game8.co/games/Animal-Crossing-New-Horizons/archives/281320